# Java - how to use .class files and .jar files

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I have a class library where the developer insists on distributing .class files (and libJNI) rather than a .jar file.  For the record it is a SWIG binding and Java conventions are not  a high priority.

I also use a few other class libraries distributed as .jar files.

I have Java a number of applications developed with NetBeans and a Matlab app.  Running from NetBeans or Matlab I'm able to set the classpath to to the .class files. Actually the folder above contains a folder which matches the package name.

My problem is running a Java application from the command line.  The `-cp` option doesn't work and I got a class not found exception.  I have tried to use paths to the package folder and to the class files.

I assume that the issue is that the class path in the manifest is overriding the command line option.  I have not found a way to add a path to the manifest entry.

I can get it working by packaging the  library into a .jar but I'd rather not include that in my install instructions.

I suspect I need a custom class loader to work with it the way it is.  Please tell me that I'm wrong.

**N.B.**  I've been using stackoverflow for years and found the best answers on the web.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can always put those .class files into a jar yourself. Just make sure the directory structure (packages) is correct.

Comment: how are you starting java process using command line. share the command. also did you try putting the folder(in which .class file resides) in classpath

Comment: Wow that was fast. The command line is kind of long here's just the pertinent part: "java  -cp /usr/lib64/java/nds2 -jar ~/NetBeansProjects/ligo/OdcPlot/dist/OdcPlot.jar --start 1041984016"  nds2 is the package name (and folder).  I tried with and without that.

Comment: The problem creating my own jar is the JNI dynamic library is system dependent and in an ideal world I could distribute my app and use the installed class library in a system independent way.  But that is what I'm doing now in my test environment and it works.

Comment: @areeda You cannot use the `-cp` argument with the `-jar` argument; see [the java executable documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/#basic) for details. Also, the when adding directories to a classpath you must use the base of the package as the directory. To include the type `foo.Bar` in the `/baz/foo` directory you would add `/baz` to the classpath.

Comment: Thanks McDowell!  I read the link you listed and don't see the limitation that you can't use -cp and -jar in the same command.  I believe it, for sure.  If I can find it in Oracle documentation I may be able to convince the developer of the class library to package it as a jar.

Comment: *Nevermind** the classpath, jar incompatib8ility is in the java man page.